# How to add a directory to the PATH?

Tags: environment-variables

How do I add a directory to the `$PATH` in Ubuntu and make the changes permanent?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables There is all you need to know. I found out that a lot of the input here was incorrect or at least the method was not suggested. This is a great piece of information that will let you figure out where to modify your environment variable based on the reason you are doing it and exactly how to do it without screwing everything up (like I did following some of the aforementioned bad advice). So long, and thanks for all the fish!

Answer (score 607, accepted):

## Using ~/.profile to set $PATH

A path set in `.bash_profile` will only be set in a bash login shell (`bash -l`).
If you put your path in `.profile` it will be available to your complete desktop session. That means even metacity will use it.

For example `~/.profile`:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
  PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
fi
```

Btw, you can check the PATH variable of a process by looking at its environment in `/proc/[pid]/environ` (replace [pid] with the number from `ps axf`). E.g. use `grep -z "^PATH" /proc/[pid]/environ`

### Note:

`bash` as a login shell doesn't parse `.profile` if either `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` exists. From `man bash` :

> it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that
>   order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists
>   and is  readable.

See the [answers below](https://askubuntu.com/a/226947) for information about `.pam_environment`, or `.bashrc` for interactive non-login shells, or set the value globally for all users by putting a script into `/etc/profile.d/` or use `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` to affect the display managers session.

Comment: Cool, that worked. I saw where it will auto add the bin dir if I make it so I just used that instead of scripts. TY.

Comment: On Xbunutu .profile isn't be executed so I put it in .bashrc and it works.

Comment: This piece of documentation is very well done: [Official documentation about environment variable](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables). Consider reading it (not to say that is updated to the last version of the rules to add values to environment variable).

Comment: If you were thinking of using spaces in the PATH statement like: PATH = "... you're in for a treat: Bash will fail to parse it and just respond that PATH isn't a command.

Comment: @LiveWireBT: Could you drop into the [AU general chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and discuss where you got the info from your edit March 7???

Comment: Where in  .profile do we add the path ??

Comment: What is this if used for? Can't I just use the inner part?

Comment: I've still got no idea where to add my extra path part to.  I need to add the android SDK to my path... `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` So I add it to it?

Comment: Keep in mind .profile is used on login and thus you have to logout-login again for it to be used (closing and reopening the terminal is not enough). @JamieHutber the path is `$WHERE_YOU_INSTALLED_THE_SDK/platform-tools` and `$WHERE_YOU_INSTALLED_THE_SDK/tools`

Comment: ~/.profile still works for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: When someone sudos as you, .profile doesn't get used.

Comment: On Elementary OS (based on Ubuntu 18.04), `.profile` wasn't being executed. So, I had to put this in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Sorry for non-constructive comment but... has anyone an explanation why they had to make it so complicated?

Comment: @Display Name  I can relate to that sentiment. I get having system-wide PATH entries as distinct to those available to a given user account., e.g /etc files like profile, bashrc, etc. It's good to be able to add a new PATH entry for the duration of a terminal session: otherwise entries made for packages later discarded will clog it up. But having to set a new entry each time you use a package is also a nuisance. Hence the need for permanent additons to PATH. For a fuller explanation, read https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bashrc-vs-bash-profile-vs-profile  This says nothing about other shells !

Answer (score 475):

Edit `.bashrc` in your home directory and add the following line:

```
export PATH="/path/to/dir:$PATH"
```

You will need to source your `.bashrc` or logout/login (or restart the terminal) for the changes to take effect. To source your `.bashrc`, simply type

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: How do you "source your `.bashrc`"? How do you "restart the terminal"?

Comment: In bash it is simply '. .bashrc'

Comment: I was making the assumption that you were in your home directory. since that's where the .bashrc you want to edit is.

Comment: `.bashrc` is not the right place for setting environment variables. They should go in `.profile` or `.pam_environment`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles

Comment: @LaoTzu `. .bashrc` not `.bashrc` :) or `source .bashrc` for that matter

Comment: True here @Ophidian

Comment: What if $PATH is used before path: `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/dir"`?

Comment: Before or after is fine, but if you add it to the end then it will have no effect for any executables with naming collisions.  Your copy of an executable will get ignored in favour of one found earlier in the list of directories that make up the PATH.

Comment: Don't forget that ":$PATH" at the end, or you'll have to log into a tty (by using ctrl+alt+F2) and edit it in using /usr/bin/nano .profile Happened to me!

Comment: Tried this but messed all commands from terminal. Whenever trying cd or ls or whatever, it said this was not available and that they could either be invoked with /bin/ls OR added to the PATH. Maybe I misunderstood this solution but to fix this I just undid changed to .bashrc file and restarted pc

Answer (score 194):

The recommended place to define permanent, *system-wide* environment variables applying to all users is in:

```
/etc/environment
```

(which is where the default `PATH` is defined)

This will work in desktop or console, gnome-terminal or TTY, rain or shine ;)

- To edit, open the terminal and type:

  ```
  sudoedit /etc/environment
  ```

  (or open the file using `sudo` in your favorite text editor)

To make it work without rebooting, run `. /etc/environment` or `source /etc/environment`. Since this file is just a simple script it will run and assign the new path to the `PATH` environment variable. To check run `env` and see the `PATH` value in the listing.

*Related:*

- [EnvironmentVariables - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: and then you need to reboot for changes to take effect...

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Provisioning a throw-away vm image via vagrant and needed to add node and npm to the path.

Comment: To take changes in effect run . /etc/environement (yes, dot, a space and /etc/environment). Since this file is just a simple script it will run and assign the new path to the PATH environment variable. To check run env and see the PATH value in the listing.

Comment: I needed to run `source /etc/environment` to reload the changes

Comment: @JohnnyAW: source is equivalent to the initial dot, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command).

Comment: Now that `gksudo` is deprecated, you can just use `sudo`.

Comment: From the linked documentation _"It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. ... Note: Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment. "_, so it isn't a script and you can't use the variable itself as in `PATH=$PATH:/path`.

Comment: should be the accepted answer, as far as I can tell other ways to set the path, through dot files like `/home/you/.profile` have down-sides.

Comment: Given a /path/to/directory I want to add, is there then a command I can execute to add that, instead of manually editing the file?

Comment: source /etc/environment is needed to patchup with the updates

Answer (score 69):

I think the canonical way in Ubuntu is:

- create a new file under `/etc/profile.d/`

  ```
   sudo vi /etc/profile.d/SCRIPT_NAME.sh
  ```
- add there:

  ```
   export PATH="$PATH:YOUR_PATH_WITHOUT_TRAILING_SLASH"
  ```
- and give it execute permission

  ```
   sudo chmod a+x /etc/profile.d/SCRIPT_NAME.sh
  ```

Comment: It is usually safer to add your custom path to the end of PATH instead of the beginning.  This avoids accidentally replacing system commands with your programs (or someone else's malicious programs). This also avoids a lot of confusion when someone else works on your system (or gives you advice) and they get unexpected results from commands you have "replaced".

Comment: It works in my case! I `pip install cmake` but I get "WARNING: The scripts cmake, cpack and ctest are installed in '/home/q/.local/bin' which is not on PATH." So I do your script with `export PATH="$PATH:/home/q/.local/bin"` After reboot it works ok.

Answer (score 61):

For complete newbies (like I am) who are more comfortable with GUI:

1. Open your `$HOME` folder.
2. Go to *View* → *Show Hidden Files* or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.
3. Right click on `.profile` and click on *Open With Text Editor*.
4. Scroll to the bottom and add `PATH="$PATH:/my/path/foo"`.
5. Save.
6. Log out and log back in to apply changes (let Ubuntu actually load `.profile`).

Comment: Editing the .profile file is not recommended anymore.You can still use this method to edit the file .pam_environment see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: Thank @PulsarBlow! I'm not really sure what's exactly the difference and the benefit though... This is the direct URL to the relevant section: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables

Comment: This answer caused my system to stop logging in due to all paths being overridden. Using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Frisbetarian you have to make sure to add the `$PATH:` bit which includes the existing PATH definition

Comment: @dain : your comment saved my life!

Comment: home folder means not the one named home, but the one you go into when you type "cd ~" in terminal

Answer (score 48):

For persistent environment variables available to particular users only. I highly recommend Ubuntu official documentation.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Referring to documentation above, I have setup my **Android SDK path-tools** by:

1. creating `~/.pam_environment` file in home directory.
2. the content of which is `PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools`.
3. additional custom user path can be added by separating paths with **colon (:)**.
4. this requires **re-login**, which means you need to log-out and log-in back to desktop environment.

Answer (score 27):

Put that line in your `~/.bashrc` file.

It gets sourced whenever you open a terminal

**EDIT**: Based on the comments below, for a more general setting that will apply to all shells (including when you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> in Unity), add the line to your `~/.profile` file. Probably shouldn't do both however, as the path will be added twice to your `PATH` environment if you open a terminal.

Comment: Actually, I thought you set the path in either `$HOME/.profile` for personal settings, or `/etc/profile` for all users.  But if it's only needed for bash, I suppose either will work.

Comment: That's only for login shells. EDIT:Doh... I guess the system will source it when you login in to the computer.  I always thought of it like a remote login thing.

Comment: If you set it in `~/.bashrc`, it'll only be available in the terminals you open. E.g. if you hit Alt+F2 and try to run a command from that dir, it won't find it. If you set it in `~/.profile` or `~/.pam_environment`, the gnome session (or whichever DE you use) will inherit it. Appending PATH in `~/.bashrc` also has the drawback that if you open/exec bash interactively from another interactive bash shell, it'll be appended multiple times.

Comment: I haven't really looked into this for a while, so I did a search, and it seems that there are at least 95 different ways to set the path, most of which are discussed [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/60218/39753). I never figured out which one is best. I think `~/.profile` is correct for personal paths, though; that's where Ubuntu adds the `~/bin` directory.  And I confess that I exaggerated a slight bit on the number of ways - just a little.

Comment: @MartyFried, yes, to quote the bot in #bash on freenode: «The overwhelming majority of bash scripts, code, tutorials, and guides on the Internet are crap. Sturgeon was an optimist.» Using google for bash problem, you'll often find a lot of half-working solutions before you find a good one. Oh and I'd go with `~/.profile` in this case too.

Comment: @geirha - I agree that most guides on the internet in general are probably crap, especially anything linux since different distros, or even different versions of the same one, do things differently. It usually boils down to what works, but most people don't realize that what works is simply what works, not necessarily what's right or even what will always work.  I try to figure out which of the many ways is actually correct, because I hate doing things more than once - but it's not always easy. :)

Answer (score 18):

Adding it to .bashrc will work but I think the more traditional way of setting up your path variables is in .bash_profile by adding the following lines.

```
PATH=$PATH:/my/path/foo
export PATH
```

According to [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/do-i-put-path-in-bashprofile-or-bashrc-or-both-540288/) it appears as though Ubuntu's behavior is slightly different than RedHat and clones.

Comment: I don't have a .bash_profile, Should I create it?

Comment: If you have `.bashrc`, stick it in `.bashrc` instead. GUI terminals in Ubuntu are not login shells, so `.bash_profile` will not be run.

Comment: I am not running a gui shell. But from the thread above it looks like the .bashrc will work just fine.

Comment: Both will work if your shell is a login shell.  But I just tried the .bash_profile approach on one of my Ubuntu machines and even after restarting my gnome session it didn't source my .bash_profile.  So I would say that putting this in .bashrc is probably the way to go with Ubuntu.

Comment: @justingrif No, you don't need `.bash_profile`. If bash doesn't find a `.bash_profile` (when you log in interactively), it will look for `.profile` and use that instead. By default, you'll have a `.profile` and `.bashrc` in Ubuntu. And `.profile` is the correct place to set environment variables if we disregard pam_env.

Answer (score 17):

To set it system wide, append the line `export PATH=/path/you're/adding:$PATH` to the end of `/etc/profile`.

To add the directory for only the logged-in user, append the same line to `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 12):

In terminal, `cd` to `the_directory_you_want_to_add_in_the_path`

```
echo "export PATH=$(pwd):\${PATH}" >> ~/.bashrc
```

This wasn't my idea. I found this way to export path at this [blog here](http://androidexperiences.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/begginning-android-ndk-in-ubuntu-10-04-12-04/).

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo vi /etc/profile.d/SCRIPT_NAME.sh
```

add there

```
export PATH=YOUR_PATH_WITHOUT_TRAILING_SLASH:$PATH
```

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/profile.d/SCRIPT_NAME.sh` is easier for beginners.

Comment: For beginners, `gksu gedit /etc/profile.d/SCRIPT_NAME.sh` is even easier.

Answer (score 9):

The recommended way to edit your `PATH` is from `/etc/environment` file

Example output of `/etc/environment`:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

For example, to add the new path of `/home/username/mydir`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/username/mydir"
```

Then, reboot your PC.

---

> **System-wide environment variables**
>
> A suitable file for environment variable settings that affect the system as a whole (rather than just a particular user) is /etc/environment. An alternative is to create a file for the purpose in the /etc/profile.d directory.
>
> **/etc/environment**
>
> This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line.
>
> **Note:** Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment.

More info can be found here: [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: The lowest answer yet the most correct. This file is usually auto-populated bin Ubuntu with the path.

Comment: Indeed this is THE correct answer, not the others

Answer (score 7):

Whenever I "install" my folder of BASH scripts, I follow the pattern of the test for a `$HOME/bin` folder that's in most .profile files in recent versions of Ubuntu. I set a test that looks like

```
if [ -d "/usr/scripts" ]; then
   PATH="/usr/scripts:$PATH"
fi
```

It works just about 100% of the time, and leaves me free to change it in a GUI text editor with a quick "Replace all" should I ever decide to move `/scripts` somewhere closer to my `$HOME` folder. I haven't done so in 6 Ubuntu installs, but there's "always tomorrow." *S*

**BZT**

Answer (score 5):

Open your terminal, type `gedit .profile` and insert the following:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
fi

 #the following line add Bin where you dont have a Bin folder on your $HOME
    PATH="$PATH:/home/mongo/Documents/mongodb-linux-i686-2.2.2/bin"
```

Close and open terminal, it should be working.

Answer (score 4):

Even if system scripts do not use this,
in any of the cases that one wants to add a path (e.g., `$HOME/bin`) to the PATH environment variable, one should use

```
PATH="${PATH:+${PATH}:}$HOME/bin"
```

for appending (instead of `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"`),
and

```
PATH="$HOME/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"
```

for prepending (instead of `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"`).

This avoids the spurious leading/trailing colon when `$PATH` is initially empty, which can have undesired effects.

See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162891/append-to-path-like-variable-without-creating-leading-colon-if-unset

Answer (score 3):

Put it to your `~/.bashrc` or whatevershell you use rc (or to beforementioned `~/.profile`) AND `~/.xsessionrc` so it will also work in X (outside shell).

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu edit the `~/.bashrc` and add the following line.

`. ~/.bash_profile`

Then edit your .bash_profile as you need.....

Comment: Downvoted because you didn't explain how to "edit your `.bash_profile` as you need". What exactly do I need to do to the `.bash_profile`?

Comment: This is the wrong way. `.profile` or `.bash_profile` should source `.bashrc`. Not the other way around.